# Position sprite background in center

Tags: css, sprite, background-position

I have a sprite for my icons. One of them is 29px*29px, but the div using that icon is actually 35px*35px (it has padding: 6px).
I would like to align the icon vertically and horizontally. I didn't make 35px*35px image because the div size might change later.
Is there any solution, or do I have to export the icon in the right dimensions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use negative coordinates in your `background:` declaration, like this:

```
background: url('sprite.png') -3px -3px no-repeat;
```

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't work because a part of another icon in the sprite is shown

Comment: In that case, you'll have to make a new background image, or somehow cover the parts you don't want to appear.